# Modify CSV file input from spiders while launching CrawlerProcess / Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am launching in parallel several spiders with `CrawlerProcess`, just like that.

```
def main():

    # ----- This part launch all given spiders ----- #

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    process.crawl(FirstSpider)
    process.crawl(SecondSpider)
    process.crawl(ThirdSpider)
    process.crawl(EtcSpider)

    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

All spiders work based on a CSV input file which contain information to look for on websites. Here is a sample :

```
class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "first_bot"

    def start_requests(self):
        base_url = "https://example.fr/catalogsearch/result/?q="
        script_dir = osp.dirname(osp.realpath(__file__))
        file_path = osp.join(script_dir, 'files', 'to_collect_firstbot.csv')
        input_file = open(file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        for row in reader:
            if row:
                url = row[0]
                absolute_url = base_url + url
                print(absolute_url)
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    absolute_url,
                    meta={
                        "handle_httpstatus_list": [302, 301, 502],
                    },
                    callback=self.parse
                )
```

It works, but I could have to modify the input file name, which is recorded for each spider.

Is it possible to keep a default "customized" file on all spiders scripts and then into core.py file (launching all spiders), modify if needed the CSV input file (in this case the file and name would be the same for all spiders)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to your spider crawl which I think is what you need to make this work.

Change your code to:

```
class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "first_bot"

    file_name = 'to_collect_firstbot.csv' # <- we are gonna change this variable later

    def start_requests(self):
        base_url = "https://example.fr/catalogsearch/result/?q="
        script_dir = osp.dirname(osp.realpath(__file__))
        file_path = osp.join(script_dir, 'files', self.file_name) # here we use the argument
        input_file = open(file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore")
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        for row in reader:
            if row:
                url = row[0]
                absolute_url = base_url + url
                print(absolute_url)
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    absolute_url,
                    meta={
                        "handle_httpstatus_list": [302, 301, 502],
                    },
                    callback=self.parse
                )
```

And now when launching your spider, just pass them as arguments in the process crawl invocation:

```
def main():

    # ----- This part launch all given spiders ----- #

    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    process.crawl(FirstSpider, file_name='custom_file1.csv')
    process.crawl(SecondSpider, file_name='custom_file2.csv')
    process.crawl(ThirdSpider)
    process.crawl(EtcSpider, file_name='custom_file_whatever.csv')

    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Check that the third invocation isn't setting the `file_name` argument, meaning that the spider will use the default one specified in the spider code:

```
file_name = 'to_collect_firstbot.csv'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

[crawl](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.Crawler.crawl) takes arguments and you may use them from within [from_crawler](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.from_crawler) of your spider.